# Why does my Django request.method is 'GET' not 'POST'?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I met this strange problem when doing a pre-populated form.
In my template, the form method is clearly stated as `POST`:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
```

But in my view function, the request.method turns out to be `GET`.

Below is my view function:

```
def editProfile(request,template_name):
    theprofile = request.user.profile

    print theprofile.fullname

    notificationMSG = ''
    print request.method

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST,request.FILES, instance=theprofile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            notificationMSG = "success！"

    else:
        form = UserProfileForm()
        print "error"

    dic = {'form':form,
           'notificationMSG':notificationMSG}

    return render_to_response(template_name, dic, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

When I run it, it prints out `GET`.
Anyone met this odd before?

Comment: when you submit the form, you aren't running any javascript are you?

Answer (score 6):

In my case I was missing a "/" at the end of action in the HTML Template, while posting.

Comment: I spent 1 hour trying to understand why it wasn't working. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 3):

When you are loading the form and retrieving remote data by hitting a url, the request method is GET.
When you fill the form values and submit the form(with post method) i.e. insert/update remote data, the request method is POST.

So, in your code when you print `request.method`, the output is GET when you are loading the form. This has nothing to do with your pre-populated form.

Answer (score 1):

Every time I submitted my form with `action=""` I was getting a GET response, but once I filled the actual URL `action="/client/"` it went through as a POST.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps I needed so far to solve this kind of error:

1. Add `method="post"` to your `<form>` element
2. Add a missing "/" at the end of the url at the `action` property on your `<form>` element
3. Add a `type="submit"` to your `<button>` element

Ps. Don't forget to add `{% csrf_token %}` after your `<form>`.

Answer (score -1):

I am also facing this problem but, In my case, in input type, I have written
type =" button" when I change it to type="submit" it get resolved.

Sorry, I get misunderstood when again I face the same problem then I got actual solution.